# Using INDEX/MATCH to get a mutiple answers. How do I get the Tier Column to be resulted as Ideal Column?

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula

I am trying to get the Tier Column (F10:F19) to appear the answer as the Ideal Column (G10:G19). Anyone have a workaround to this? Would Concatenate work with Index Match?

[image]

Comment: if u use office 365 'XLOOKUP()` is available. https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-xlookup-function

Comment: It is okay. Thank you. Found a workaround

Comment: Happy that you did.. congratulations.. !! ( + good job @ sharing the answer. ) /(^_^)

Answer (score 1):

=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$22:$A$26,E10)),$B$22:$B$26,""))

This works perfectly fine!